# why does perl while (<>) fail to count or print the first line

Tags: perl, while-loop, stdin

I want to count the lines in a file and print a string which depends on the line number. But my `while` loop misses the first line. I believe the `while (<>)` construct is necessary to increment the `$n` variable; anyway, is not this construct pretty standard in perl?

How do I get the `while` loop to print the first line? Or should I not be using `while`?

```
> printf '%s\n%s\n' dog cat
dog
cat
> printf '%s\n%s\n' dog cat | perl -n -e 'use strict; use warnings; print; '
dog
cat
> printf '%s\n%s\n' dog cat | perl -n -e 'use strict; use warnings; while (<>) { print; } ' 
cat
> 
> printf '%s\n%s\n' dog cat | perl -n -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $n=0; while (<>) { $n++; print "$n:"; print; } ' 
1:cat
```

Answer (score 4):

The `man perlrun` shows:

> ```
>    -n   causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename
>         arguments somewhat like sed -n or awk:
>
>           LINE:
>             while (<>) {
>                 ...             # your program goes here
>             }
>
>         Note that the lines are not printed by default.  See "-p" to have lines printed.  If a file named by an
>         argument cannot be opened for some reason, Perl warns you about it and moves on to the next file.
>
>         Also note that "<>" passes command line arguments to "open" in perlfunc, which doesn't necessarily
>         interpret them as file names.  See  perlop for possible security implications.
>  ...
>  ...     
>
>       "BEGIN" and "END" blocks may be used to capture control before or after the implicit program loop, just as in awk.
> ```

So, in fact you running this script

```
LINE:
    while (<>) {
        # your progrem start
        use strict;
        use warnings;
        my $n=0;
        while (<>) {
            $n++;
            print "$n:";
            print;
        }
        # end
    }
```

Solution, just remove the `-n`.

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' dog cat | perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; my $n=0; while (<>) { $n++; print "$n:"; print; }'
```

Will print:

```
1:dog
2:cat
```

or

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' dog cat | perl -ne 'print ++$n, ":$_"'
```

with the same result

or

```
printf '%s\n%s\n' dog cat | perl -pe '++$n;s/^/$n:/'
```

but the ikegami's solution

```
printf "one\ntwo\n" | perl -ne 'print "$.:$_"'
```

is the **BEST**

Comment: Then what for `$.` variable? [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: `perl -pe '$.: ' somefile` should be sufficient (Windows: perl -pe "print \"$.: \"" 4k.m3u)

Comment: @Polar Bear, That's not valid code. You mean `perl -pe'$_ = "$.:$_"'` But I'd go for the more readable `perl -ne'print "$.:$_"'`

Comment: @ikegami -- for me this code works in Windows. Why? I do not know -- at first I did same as you, but then tried without `$_` and it still produced desired output.

Comment: @Polar Bear I was referring to the first snippet

Comment: @ikegami -- if first snippet for Windows then I confirm that it works and produces same result as `perl -pe "print \"$.: $_\"". Unix version was not tested as I did not had access to Unix/Linux computer at that moment.

Comment: @PolarBear How can `perl -pe'$.: '` possibly work? It's a syntax error.  There's bare `:` in it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to figure out what your one-liner is actually doing. The [B::Deparse](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse) module has a way to show you how perl interpreted your source code. It's actually from the O (capital letter O, not zero) namespace that you can load with `-M` ([ikegami explains this on Perlmonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=804232)):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -ne 'while(<>){print}' foo bar
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
        print $_;
    }
-e syntax OK
```

Heh, googling for the module link shows [I wrote about this for The Effective Perler](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/05/use-bdeparse-to-see-what-perl-thinks-the-code-is/). Same example. I guess I'm not that original.

If you can't change the command line, perhaps because it's in the middle of a big script or something, you can set options in `PERL5OPT`. Then those options last for just the session. I hate changing the original scripts because it seems that no matter how careful I am, I mess up something (how many times has my brain told me "hey dummy, you know what a git branch is, so you should have used that first"):

```
$ export PERL5OPT='-MO=Deparse'
```